# 'Long(s) for' or 'be longing for'

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

Is there a subtle difference between:

> It's common knowledge that Anna longs for a baby.

and

> It's common knowledge that Anna is longing for a baby.

If I want to use the sentence and it's spoken at the present time, which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the difference is subtle. The progressive aspect emphasizes that the action is ongoing (continuous). I assume that Anna is not suddenly starting to long for a baby right now, so I'd probably use the progressive aspect. (The simple present certainly isn't wrong, though.)

You could also use the present perfect if the action began at an earlier time and continues into the current time:

> It's common knowledge that Anna has been longing for a baby.